# JavaScript , validate html form for both onkeyup and submit

Tags: javascript, html

I've see a lot of solution and questions similar to this but none of them helped me out

here is a simple html form with JavaScript validation

> > log error message on key up when the value of input fields are less than required length (less than 5)

> > log error message on submit when input fields are empty (first Name and last Name)

> > problem is when I click submit button form is submitted regardless of errors

I have tried `preventDefault()` and `return false` but none of them worked out

how can I improve the code to make them work correctly? for both key up and submit

```js
let fname = document.getElementById('fname');
let lname = document.getElementById('lname');
form = document.querySelector('#myForm');

function checkFirstName() {
  let valid = true;
  if (fname.value.length < 5) {
    console.log('first name must be greater than 5');
    valid = false;
  }
}

function checkLastName() {
  let valid = true;
  if (lname.value.length < 5) {
    console.log('last name must be greater than 5');
    valid = false;
  }
}
form.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  switch (e.target.id) {
    case 'fname':
      checkFirstName();
      break;
    case 'lname':
      checkLastName();
      break;
  }
});

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  let isFormField = true;
  if (fname.value === '') {
    console.log('first name is required')
    isFormField = false;
  }
  if (lname.value === '') {
    console.log('last name is required')
    isFormField = false;
  }
  if (!isFormField) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return
  }
});
```

```html
<form method="get" id="myForm">
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname"></br>
    <small class="small" id="small"></small>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname"></br>
    <small class="small" id="small"></small>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="send">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: There's a _"Tidy"_ button in the snippet editor. Please use it before you add the snippet to your question.

Comment: It's `<br />` and not `</br>`

Comment: You are only calling `checkFirstName` and `checkLastName` on `input` event. If user submit form then you are not validating the inputs.

Comment: @HR01M8055  when I use it outside the if condition it stops the from submission even if there is no errors

Comment: @HR01M8055
 can u pls demonstrate it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've moved all the validation of `firstname` in the function `checkFirstName` and `lastname` in `checkLastName`. Just to be concise

You can make it separate, But you have to remember that form will only submit if `checkFirstName` and `checkLastName` returns true

```js
let fname = document.getElementById('fname');
let lname = document.getElementById('lname');
form = document.querySelector('#myForm');

function checkFirstName() {
  if (fname.value.length >= 5) return true;
  if (fname.value === "") {
    console.log('Last name is required')
    return false
  }
  console.log('first name must be greater than 5');
  return false;
}

function checkLastName() {
  if (lname.value.length >= 5) return true;
  if (lname.value === "") {
    console.log('Last name is required')
    return false
  }
  console.log('last name must be greater than 5');
  return false;
}
form.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  switch (e.target.id) {
    case 'fname':
      checkFirstName();
      break;
    case 'lname':
      checkLastName();
      break;
  }
});

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  if (!checkFirstName() || !checkLastName()) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return
  }
});
```

```html
<form method="get" id="myForm">
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname"></br>
    <small class="small" id="small"></small>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname"></br>
    <small class="small" id="small"></small>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="send">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: can you write the same code and put e.preventDefault(); outside the if condition?

Comment: This code also works, What's wrong with this?

Comment: nothing wrong  you asked me why I use it inside if condition, I thought you have better solution of using it outside if condition

Comment: I apologize for that, I was thinking something wrong. But this solution will work for you.

Comment: Would you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer if it solved your issue?